# Make a jsonstring correct

Tags: c#, json, replace, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity together with pushwoosh and want to send data with my push and am having no problem with this.

The issue comes when I get the json string from pushwoosh!?! It looks like this:

```
{“maps”:{“badge”:1,”sound”:”num7.mp3”,”alert”:”testtest made a move”,”u”:”{\”custom\”:\”{“gameid”:”mpobiX5B5P”}\”}”}
```

What I want to be able to get into an array or something like this is what is inside "custom". The issue is the escaped parts. I have no control on how I receive the jsonstring but needs to handle it afterwards so I can remove the escapes?!?

I have tried this:

```
jsonstring = jsonstring.Replace(@"\""", "\"");
jsonstring = jsonstring.Replace("\\\"", "\");
```

Both with no success :-(

Can somebody please help me with this...

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: [Your json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936313/retrieve-nested-jsonobjects) was invalid, and now worse. Even if you fix `“` and `”` it will be still invalid.

Comment: So what you are saying is there is no way to make this jsonstring valid?

Comment: Mansa, just for this specific case if you remove `\\`s it may be correct(I didn't test it). But this will not be a safe way. In short. No.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `"` in your second attempt

```
s = s.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyJ2Y0

But the result is still an invalid JSON. There are two extra quotes in there.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all you need to delete "\".

Make str_replace("\", "", $pushwooshString)

After this you need to replace “ and ” to "

Make str_replace("“", "", $pushwooshString) and str_replace("”", "", $pushwooshString)